# How do you open a custom URL in a new tab with content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to open a new tab to access a custom url with HTML content.

I know that window.open(url, "_blank") will open a new tab but I can seem to add a content in it.

This is the code that I am using:

> var strWindowFeatures =
>   "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
>
> window.open(e.MediaUrl, "_blank", strWindowFeatures);

The url that I am accessing is a download url, so I need to add a content like "We are currently generating your file, please do not close this tab."
Currently, I am getting a blank page and then, automatically closes when the file is downloading.

Comment: e.MediaUrl is the page, that you have created? Means do you have any sort of control on that URL, or on the contents of page of that URL?

Comment: e.MediaUrl's value is being generated from backend. This is a url that will download a file from our storage, so I don't have a control on it.

Comment: How about showing a message before opening the new tab.

Comment: I'll look for another solution for this but showing a message before opening the new tab might be fine.

Comment: Because you are saying we do not have access to the download page URL, I think we don't have another way of doing it. Just consider you are downloading a sample pdf file from web, And u dont have access to that download page, how can we add a message in that page. All we have is a URL to which we dont have full access.

Comment: I guess I'll just create a new view for the download page. Thanks for the help, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you might consider doing is:

---

1. replace "window.open(e.MediaUrl, "_blank", strWindowFeatures);" with

> var myWindow = window.open(e.MediaUrl, "_blank", strWindowFeatures);

and then add this line:

> myWindow.document.write("
>
> Currently, I am getting a blank page and
>   then, automatically closes when the file is downloading.
>
> ");

REFERENCE: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open3

Comment: myWindow.document.write - this works but it doesn't access the given custom url